# Algorithm to index 2d points by clusters

Tags: java, algorithm, indexing, geometry, cluster-analysis

I have a problem to solve for which I did not find any usable algorithms after an internet search and I have not been able to come up with a satisfying solution myself yet.

**Problem definition:**

I am given a set of N-many points, defined by their X- and Y-coordinates, and I am supposed to give each point a unique index between 0 and N. There are a few conditions though:

1) if the geometric distance between two points is small, the difference between their indices should be small too.

2) if point A has a higher X-coordinate as point B it should have a higher index value too.

3) if point A has a higher Y-coordinate as point B it should have a higher index value too.

**Other:**

The algorithm does not need to be particularly fast or efficient as the data is fairly small (50 ~ 100 points).

I need this algorithm for a user interface with only 2 buttons for navigation through a data set. With one button the user selects the next point and with the other the user selects the previous point.

All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

**Example Image:**

This is an example of what a result *could* look like. Please note how the conditions are not fulfilled for all points (as that would be impossible) but how the indices are still nicely distributed among the clusters.

[image: Example Output]

Comment: That's an pretty ill-conditioned problem (XY-points and 1) is impossible alone). Be much more formal about the maths / cost-function / objective! (and your task sounds more like you just need some kind of multi-dim sorting)

Comment: I know that it is impossible to have all of these conditions apply to all points. What I am looking for is a good approximation which fulfills the conditions for most points. As I said in my question, this is for a user interface. It does not have to be perfect but it has to "feel right".

Comment: Without detailed maths it's hard to understand how this UI should behave. This also applies to the kind of input, because for some inputs a given solution will behave quite chaotic (poor user).

Comment: I have added an image to hopefully explain the desired behaviour a little better. I hope that from the image it becomes obvious how this indexing is more user friendly than a purely random sequence. Moving the selection forward and backward the user would move mostly within clusters and sometimes *jump* to a cluster nearby.

Comment: It seems you already made that decision on how it should behave: but i have to admit: given such a limited UI i would rather jump straight in one dimension (left to right) as this is simple / has no hidden parameters and given the assumption, that the point i want is random, it needs the same number of steps on average.

Comment: You could try to do this: Sort the coordinates by the x value and start assigning indices to them one by one. If there's more than one y-value that maps to the same x-value, assign a smaller index to the one that has the samller y-value. I guess that would be a decent approximation to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the points by the [Morton curve aka Z-order (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve).

Then assign numbers.

Comment: This is a great idea! Thank you for your help.